# global variable return in function

Tags: javascript, arrays, global

I have using node module that reads firewall ip rules from ubuntu and using this function:

```
function lists(table, chain, cb) {
var ip = [];
// Accepts optional table argument
if(!cb) {
    cb = chain;
    chain = table;
    table = undefined;
}
var rule = {
    list : true,
    chain : chain,
            table : table,
    action : '-L',
    sudo : true
};

lazy(iptables(rule).stdout)
    .lines
    .map(String)
    .skip(2)
    .map(function (line) {
        // packets, bytes, target, pro, opt, in, out, src, dst, opts
        var fields = line.trim().split(/\s+/, 9);

        ip.push(fields[7]);
        console.log(ip);

    })
    return ip;
}
```

The problem is that console.log(ip) gets correct ip values and return ip gets undefined variable value...so how can i return array of ip in return(ip) so when i call this function from main program then i can compare if ip in array...i define global array variable at the beggining of function (var ip = [];) but return ip gets undefined variable....how can i return global ip array variable in return(ip)?

Comment: If a variable is global, it is accessible from anywhere, I don't understand why you need to return a global variable

Comment: this function is inside node js module...and from main program i called this module function that needs to return ip array so this way i can get ip

Comment: do you know where lazy() comes from and how it works? it looks like it is asynchronously  evaluating a stream from stdout, so return would be undefined. maybe try to rewrite it in a synchronous way.

Comment: could you rewrite it? this is module: https://github.com/pkrumins/node-iptables