# Not understanding Global and Script variable to function return variable

Tags: powershell, variables, environment-variables, global-variables

This is a good explanation.
[global variable return in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608175/global-variable-return-in-function)
However I am still trying to wrap my head around why this is not working.
The correct answer is to continue modifying the script so I am not using the Script: or Global: state variable.  This was done for ease of use with multi threaded/Job PS Script so I can extract the data from each thread/job.  I believe I am at a point where I can modify the script to send the data without the use of the Script: or Global: variable state.  However I would like to understand why this is not working.  Everything in the script works perfectly up until the closure of the function.  even the "return" and "return variable" statement shows it has the data I want it to return.  Yet when the function finally closes, I get a different dataset, which is telling me the jobs not the jobs data.

Yes I know I can reference the data from the global variable outside the function by calling Script: or Global: . But I would like to understand why this does not work and or how to make it work. If possible.

Here is the surrounding code.
Simplistically as long as I exist inside the function the data and global: and or Script: variable and other variables are correct.  However once the the function is complete, it says it is returning the correct data set from the Script: or Global: Variable.  But I actually get the get-job info.  and a bunch of blank records.

$MyPrinterUsers does not receive the dataset of $ReturnUsersWhoHavePrinted
$MyPrinterUsers receives get-job records and all the additional rows that match $ReturnUsersWhoHavePrinted as blank.
However stepping thru the code the return variable shows the correct dataset just before the function closes.

What I want as a result is once "Get-PrinterWhoPrintedLogs" completes I want $Script:AllUsersWhoHavePrinted dataset from the received jobs to be exported/returned to the parent requested variable of $MyPrinterUsers.

I have modified this script to not use the global: or Script: variable and I get the same result.  Not understanding.

```
FUNCTION processCompletedJobs
{
    Param   (
                $Finishing = $False,
                $_NumberofDaysPast = -366,
                $_Filter = $null,
                $_FilterUnique = $False
            )

    
    [array] $data = @()
    $jobs = Get-Job -State Completed
    $jobs_Failed = Get-Job -State Failed
    #$JobsProcessed = 
    $data =$null
    foreach( $job in $jobs ) 
    {
        #$job
        #Get Specific Data Set
        $data1 = Receive-Job $job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob 
        #$data.count
        #if ( $data.GetType() -eq [Object[]] ){
        #}
        #Remove-Job $job 
        if ($data1.count -gt 0)
        {
            if ($Finishing -eq $true) 
            {
                Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "FINISHING UP PROCESSING LAST FEW JOBS:"
            }
            Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "Number of Print Jobs Events from ($($job.name)) to Process: $($data1.count)"
        }
        #Combine Data Set
        $data += $data1 #| select PrinterName, ComputerName, UserName -Unique 
    }
    foreach( $job_Failed in $jobs_Failed ) 
    {
        Write-ColorMessage -MessageType Warning -Message "Print Jobs Events from ($($job_Failed.name)) Failed to Process"
        Get-Job -Id $job_Failed.id | Remove-Job
        $data1 = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational"; ID=307; StartTime=(Get-Date).AddDays($_NumberofDaysPast)} -ComputerName $job_Failed.Name |
                                                                                                                    Select-Object -Property TimeCreated,
                                                                                                                                            @{label='UserName';expression={$_.properties[2].value}},
                                                                                                                                            @{label='ComputerName';expression={$_.properties[3].value}},
                                                                                                                                            @{label='PrinterName';expression={$_.properties[4].value}},
                                                                                                                                            @{label='PrintSize';expression={$_.properties[6].value}},
                                                                                                                                            @{label='Pages';expression={$_.properties[7].value}},
                                                                                                                                            @{label='PrintServer';expression={$_.MachineName}}  
        $data += $data1
    }

    $a=1
    
    #Merge Data Sets
    if ($_FilterUnique)
    {
        $Script:AllUsersWhoHavePrinted += $data | Select-Object $_filter -Unique | Sort-Object $_filter
    }
    else
        {
            $Script:AllUsersWhoHavePrinted += $data | Select-Object $_filter | Sort-Object $_filter
        }

    if ($data.count -gt 0)
    {
        #if ($Finishing -eq $true)
        #{
        #    Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "FINISHING UP PROCESSING LAST FEW JOBS:"
        #}
        #Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "Number of Print Jobs Events from ($Event_ComputerName) to Process: $($data.count)"
        Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "Number of Print Jobs Events TOTAL to Process: $($Script:AllUsersWhoHavePrinted.count)"
        

    }
}

Function Get-PrinterWhoPrintedLogs
{
    Param
    (
        $PrintServerNames = @("sv-oracleprint1","sv-oracleprint2","Rictx-print-p01","Rictx-print-p02","Rictx-cprint-p1","MHOH-CPRINT-P1","MTHOH-PRINT-P03","CORTX-PRINT-P01","PENFL-PRINT-P01","cdc-print","CN110","DA110","ito100","MarOH-PRINT-P01","mthoh-print-p01","mthoh-print-p02","PO100","SV-OHBA-001","SV-OHBUR-01","SV-OHBUR-02","SV-OHDS-001","sv-ohne-001","SV-OHPA-001","sv-ohtm-001","TE110"),
        $ExcludedUsersList = $Null,
        $ExcludeUsers = $True,
        $Script_Log = $Null,
        $NumberofDaysPast = -366,
        $ConcurrentJobProcess = 50,
        $Filter = $Null,  #@("PrinterName", "PrintServer", "ComputerName", "UserName")
        $FilterUnique = $false

    )
    . "\\rictx-script-p2\Scripts\Module\General\Write-Color.ps1"
    . "\\rictx-script-p2\Scripts\Module\OS\Print Server\Events\Set-PrintServerEvent_Operational.ps1"
    . "\\rictx-script-p2.ohdc.com\Scripts\Module\General\Limit-JobWithTime.ps1"

    

    if ( ($ExcludedUsersList  -eq $Null) -and ($ExcludeUsers -eq $True) )
    {
        $ExcludedUsersList = Get-ADGroup -Identity "OHD - Service Desk Users" | Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser | Where {($_.Enabled -eq $true)}
        $ExcludedUsersList += Get-ADGroup -Identity "OHD – PC Support Team" | Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser | Where {($_.Enabled -eq $true)}
        $ExcludedUsersList += Get-ADGroup -Identity "OHD – Network Support Team" | Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser| Where {($_.Enabled -eq $true)}
        $ExcludedUsersList += Get-ADGroup -Identity "G Help Desk" | Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser| Where {($_.Enabled -eq $true)}
        $ExcludedUsersList += Get-ADGroup -Identity "Domain Admins" | Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser| Where {($_.Enabled -eq $true)}
        $ExcludedUsersList += Get-ADGroup -Identity "PC Support" | Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser| Where {($_.Enabled -eq $true)}
    }
    #get-adgroup -Filter {Name -like "gprt_*"} | %{ Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.DistinguishedName }
    #(get-adgroup -Filter {Name -like "gprt_*"})[0] | %{ Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.DistinguishedName }
    
    Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "Number of Users who have printed to Exclude: $($ExcludedUsersList.count)"
    Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "Filtering Event Log, Excluding users from Global Printer Access."






  



    #Begin Processing Event Logs from servers
    $SW = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
    $Script:AllUsersWhoHavePrinted  = @()
    $ComputerCounter = 0
    $Computers = $PrintServerNames  #For reference Use only for multithread script since I have build the framework to use $computers I am being lazy.
    foreach ($Event_ComputerName in $PrintServerNames)
    {
        #Show user activity of the multithreaded tasks to get an idea when things will complete:
         $ComputerCounter++
                    Write-Progress -Activity "Processing Print Servers Print Logs:" -Status "Querying $($_)     $ComputerCounter  of  $($Computers.Count)" -PercentComplete (($ComputerCounter/$Computers.Count) * 100)
                
                    $runningjobs = if ( ((get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }) -ne $null) ) 
                                        { if ( ((get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }).Count -ne $null) ) 
                                            {(get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }).Count} else {0} 
                                        } 
                                    else 
                                        {0}
                        
                   while  ($runningjobs  -gt $ConcurrentJobProcess)
                    {
                        #do nothing
                        processCompletedJobs  -_Filter $Filter -_FilterUnique $FilterUnique -_NumberofDaysPast $NumberofDaysPast
                        #$runningjobs = if ( (get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }).Count -ne $null) {(get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }).Count} else {0}
                        $runningjobs = if ( ((get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }) -ne $null) ) 
                                            { if ( ((get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }).Count -ne $null) ) 
                                                {(get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }).Count} else {0} 
                                            } 
                                        else 
                                            {0}
                        
                    }


                    











        #Begin validating the event log was active on the server, attempt to resolve. And Process the event log if active.

        if ( (Get-WinEvent -ListLog Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational -OutVariable PrinterLog -ComputerName $Event_ComputerName).IsEnabled -eq $true )
        {
            Get-WinEvent -ListLog Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational -OutVariable PrinterLog -ComputerName $Event_ComputerName | Select-Object -Property LogName, IsClassicLog, IsEnabled

            if ($PrinterLog.RecordCount -gt 0)
            {
                #[Datetime]::ParseExact((Get-Date).AddDays(-1),'MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss',$null).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy') 
                #Write-host "Getting event logs for the Print Service - Operational"
                Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "Processing event logs on $Event_ComputerName for the Print Service - Operational since $(((Get-Date).AddDays($NumberofDaysPast)).GetDateTimeFormats()[12])"
                if ($Script_Log -ne $null)
                {
                    $Script_Log.LogWrite("INFO: Processing $NumberofDaysPast of days in the event logs for the Print Service - Operational. Since $(((Get-Date).AddDays($NumberofDaysPast)).GetDateTimeFormats()[12])")
                }
                #Get Print Jobs done on this print server
                <#
                [object[]] $UsersWhoHavePrinted = 
                    Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational"; ID=307; StartTime=(Get-Date).AddDays($NumberofDaysPast)} -ComputerName $Event_ComputerName |
                        Select-Object -Property TimeCreated,
                                                @{label='UserName';expression={$_.properties[2].value}},
                                                @{label='ComputerName';expression={$_.properties[3].value}},
                                                @{label='PrinterName';expression={$_.properties[4].value}},
                                                @{label='PrintSize';expression={$_.properties[6].value}},
                                                @{label='Pages';expression={$_.properties[7].value}} 
                ###############################################################################################################################################################################################################

                #$NumberofDaysPast = -366
                $UsersWhoHavePrinted = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Event_ComputerName -ArgumentList $NumberofDaysPast -ScriptBlock {
                                                                                                                                        Param ($_NumberofDaysPast)
                                                                                                                                        Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational"; ID=307; StartTime=(Get-Date).AddDays($_NumberofDaysPast)} |
                                                                                                                                            Select-Object -Property TimeCreated,
                                                                                                                                                                    @{label='UserName';expression={$_.properties[2].value}},
                                                                                                                                                                    @{label='ComputerName';expression={$_.properties[3].value}},
                                                                                                                                                                    @{label='PrinterName';expression={$_.properties[4].value}},
                                                                                                                                                                    @{label='PrintSize';expression={$_.properties[6].value}},
                                                                                                                                                                    @{label='Pages';expression={$_.properties[7].value}} 
                                                                                                                                    }

                $AllUsersWhoHavePrinted += $UsersWhoHavePrinted

                Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "Number of Print Jobs Events from ($Event_ComputerName) to Process: $($UsersWhoHavePrinted.count)"
                Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "Number of Print Jobs Events TOTAL to Process: $($AllUsersWhoHavePrinted.count)"
                #>


                #Begin Multi-Threaded Job
                #Start-Job  -ScriptBlock  $function:Get_UsersWhoHavePrinted  -ArgumentList @($Event_ComputerName,$NumberofDaysPast) -Name $Event_ComputerName  #This opion works but is much slower
                Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Event_ComputerName -ArgumentList $NumberofDaysPast -AsJob  -JobName "$($Event_ComputerName)" -ScriptBlock {
                                                                                                                Param ($_NumberofDaysPast)
                                                                                                                Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational"; ID=307; StartTime=(Get-Date).AddDays($_NumberofDaysPast)} |
                                                                                                                    Select-Object -Property TimeCreated,
                                                                                                                                            @{label='UserName';expression={$_.properties[2].value}},
                                                                                                                                            @{label='ComputerName';expression={$_.properties[3].value}},
                                                                                                                                            @{label='PrinterName';expression={$_.properties[4].value}},
                                                                                                                                            @{label='PrintSize';expression={$_.properties[6].value}},
                                                                                                                                            @{label='Pages';expression={$_.properties[7].value}},
                                                                                                                                            @{label='PrintServer';expression={$_.MachineName}} 
                                                                                                            }
                #Just watching activity
                #get-job








                #Complete the process to validate the status of other job threads to see if they have completed their task.  Once Complete close out and return the full data set.
                processCompletedJobs  -_Filter $Filter -_FilterUnique $FilterUnique -_NumberofDaysPast $NumberofDaysPast
                    if ($ComputerCounter -eq $computers.Count)
                    {

                        #if ($RunningJobs_offset > $runningjobs)
                        #$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
                        #$sw.Restart()

                        if (!($sw.IsRunning))
                        {
                            #This delay counter is used to identify jobs taking to long to run
                            $sw.Start()
                            $CurrentCountofRunningJobs = $runningjobs
                        }

                        

                        #$runningjobs = ((get-job | ? { $_.state -eq "running" }).Count)
                        $runningjobs = if ( (get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }).Count -ne $null) {(get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }).Count} else {0}
                        
                        #Just watching activity
                        Get-Job

                        #Wait-Job -Job $jobs
                        while ($runningjobs -gt 0) 
                        {
                            
                            processCompletedJobs -Finishing $True -_Filter $Filter -_FilterUnique $FilterUnique -_NumberofDaysPast $NumberofDaysPast
                            if ($runningjobs -lt $CurrentCountofRunningJobs)
                            {
                                $sw.Reset()
                                $sw.Start()
                                $CurrentCountofRunningJobs = $runningjobs
                            }

                            if ( ($sw.Elapsed.Minutes -gt 30) )
                            {
                                if ( (get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }).Count -ne $null) 
                                {
                                    $Jobs = get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }
                                    foreach ($Job in $Jobs)
                                    {
                                        #Force Jobs to close
                                        Limit-JobWithTime $job -TimeInSeconds 600
                                        $output = (Receive-Job -Keep -Job $job)
                                        #$JobNameofServer = $Job.Name
                                        Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "Processing LONG RUNNING JOB:  event logs on $Event_ComputerName for the Print Service - Operational since $(((Get-Date).AddDays($NumberofDaysPast)).GetDateTimeFormats()[12])"
                                        processCompletedJobs -Finishing $True -_Filter $Filter -_FilterUnique $FilterUnique -_NumberofDaysPast $NumberofDaysPast
                                        
                                        Remove-Job $job
                                        #Try again to add the bad computers output
                                        #$data = Test-ComputerName -ComputerName $JobNameofServer
                                        #$Script:Jobs_ComputerInfo += $data

                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            # Update progress based on how many jobs are done yet.
                            #write-progress -Activity "Waiting for the Testing of Computers IP Address to be Reachable Processes to Complete" -Status "Progress: $($jobs.count-$runningjobs)  of  $($jobs.count) COMPLETED" `
                            #-PercentComplete (($jobs.count-$runningjobs)/$jobs.count*100)
                            
                            write-progress -Activity "Processing Print Servers Print Logs:" -Status "Progress: $($runningjobs) to be COMPLETED" `
                            -PercentComplete (((get-job).count-$runningjobs)/(get-job).count*100) -Verbose -ErrorVariable WriteProgressError
    
                            # After updating the progress bar, get current job count
                            $runningjobs = if ( ((get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }) -ne $null) ) { if ( ((get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }).Count -ne $null) ) {(get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }).Count} else {0} } else {0}
                            #if ( ( (get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }).Count -ne $null) -or ((get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }) -ne '') ) {(get-job | ? { $_.State -eq "running" }).Count} else {0}
                        }       
                        #$ComputerList += 

                        #if $sw
                        processCompletedJobs -Finishing $True -_Filter $Filter -_FilterUnique $FilterUnique -_NumberofDaysPast $NumberofDaysPast
                    }



                    write-progress -Activity "Processing Print Servers Print Logs:" -Completed






            }
        }
        else
            {
                #Eventlog is turned off, Attempting to Turn it on
                try
                {
                    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Event_ComputerName -ScriptBlock 
                    {
                        Write-Host "Attempting to turn on Print Services Operationsl Event Log on server: $($env:COMPUTERNAME)"
                        . "\\rictx-script-p2\Scripts\Module\OS\Print Server\Events\Set-PrintServerEvent_Operational.ps1"
                        Write-Host "Print Services Operationsl Event Log Enabled: $( ((Get-WinEvent -ListLog Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational -OutVariable PrinterLog -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME).IsEnabled) )"
                    }
                }
                catch
                    {
                        Write-Host "Print Services Operationsl Event Log on server: $($Event_ComputerName) Enabled: $( ((Get-WinEvent -ListLog Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational -OutVariable PrinterLog -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME).IsEnabled) )"
                    }
                #Since there is no records there is no need to process anything so we will continue the loop to the next computer
            }
    }




      

      #$APPLE = $Script:AllUsersWhoHavePrinted 
      #$fILTERoUTPUT =

       $T = 0    
    if ($ExcludeUsers)
    {
        #Write-host "Generating a List of users to exclude from the Log Report"
        Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "Generating a List of users to exclude from the Log Report"

        #$AllUsersWhoHavePrintedExceptExcluded = ($AllUsersWhoHavePrinted | where {$_.UserName -notin ($ExcludedUsersList.SamAccountName | Select -Unique )} | Select PrinterName, UserName -Unique  | Sort-Object PrinterName, UserName)
        
        if ($FilterUnique)
        {
            $AllUsersWhoHavePrintedExceptExcluded = (($Script:AllUsersWhoHavePrinted) | where {$_.UserName -notin ($ExcludedUsersList.SamAccountName | Select -Unique )} | Select-Object $Filter -Unique | Sort-Object $Filter)
        }
        else
            {
                $AllUsersWhoHavePrintedExceptExcluded = (($Script:AllUsersWhoHavePrinted) | where {$_.UserName -notin ($ExcludedUsersList.SamAccountName | Select -Unique )} | Select-Object $Filter | Sort-Object $Filter)
            }
        Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
        Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "Number of Print Jobs Events TOTAL to Process: $(($Script:AllUsersWhoHavePrinted).count)"
        Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "Number of Print Jobs Events TOTAL Removing Excluded Users to Process: $($AllUsersWhoHavePrintedExceptExcluded.count)"
        Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
        #Write-ColorMessage -MessageType INFO -Message "Number of Users who have printed that need verified are added to their respective GPRT_<PRINTERNAME> AD Groups: $($UserstoAddtoGPRT_Group.count)"
    
        $ReturnUsersWhoHavePrinted = $AllUsersWhoHavePrintedExceptExcluded  
    }
    else
        {
            if ($FilterUnique)
            {
                $Userswhohaveprinted_Complete = ($Script:AllUsersWhoHavePrinted)  | Select-Object $Filter -Unique | Sort-Object $Filter #| select PrinterName, ComputerName, UserName -Unique | Sort-Object PrinterName, ComputerName, UserName
            }
            Else
                {
                    $Userswhohaveprinted_Complete = ($Script:AllUsersWhoHavePrinted)  | Select-Object $Filter | Sort-Object $Filter #| select PrinterName, ComputerName, UserName -Unique | Sort-Object PrinterName, ComputerName, UserName
                }
            
            $ReturnUsersWhoHavePrinted =  $Userswhohaveprinted_Complete
        }

        Return $ReturnUsersWhoHavePrinted
}


$MyPrinterUsers = Get-PrinterWhoPrintedLogs `
                        -ExcludeUsers $false `
                        -Filter @("PrinterName", "PrintServer", "ComputerName", "UserName") `
                        -FilterUnique $True `
                        -PrintServerNames @("PrintServer1","PrintServer2")
```

Here is my different output:

[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>> $ReturnUsersWhoHavePrinted.count
2830

[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>> $ReturnUsersWhoHavePrinted.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType

---

True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>> $ReturnUsersWhoHavePrinted[0]

PrinterName           PrintServer          ComputerName      UserName

---

\SV-OHNE-001\NBPRT05 sv-ohne-001.ohdc.com \LP-OHNB-DV010Z2 OHDC1\NStahlnecker

---

---

---

PS C:\Windows\system32> $MyPrinterUsers.count
2887

PS C:\Windows\system32> $MyPrinterUsers.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType

---

True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
PS C:\Windows\system32> $MyPrinterUsers[0]

LogName                                    IsClassicLog IsEnabled

---

Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational        False      True

Comment: What does the `Invoke-Command` have to do with your question? There is no reference in your code to get output from it. What is `$Script:AllUsersWhoHavePrinted` ? There is no reference to it either. If you provided an actual minimal reproducible example your question might be easier to answer, as you have it right now it doesnt make much sense. Linking a Javascript answer to a PowerShell question doesn't make sense either, those are 2 totally different languages.

Comment: Ok I have updated the above script with all the details of the script itself.  Hope that helps. Please and Thanks.

Comment: Ok I think I see what is going on but I do not understand still. 

The return variable is providing the output of:
Get-WinEvent -ListLog Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational -OutVariable PrinterLog -ComputerName $Event_ComputerName | Select-Object -Property LogName, IsClassicLog, IsEnabled


so I comment out that variable....

Comment: Now that I comment out that variable:
I am getting a "get-job" entry as output.

yet I explicitly passed the variable I wanted to the return command.  confusing,,,, Still troubleshooting.

Comment: so found the other issue:

Needed to have a " | out-Null"  to the invoke-command as it was outputing an object to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Need to | Out-Null to the Invoke-command and get-winevent commands to remove their object from the function.